# Django with a legacy database

Tags: django, legacy-database

I need to build a django project on top of an existing database.
I'll use inspectdb as explained in the django docs and then syncdb to create the django required tables.

Is there a way to keep track of the django specific tables (admin permissions, content types...)?
I want to be able to remove django completely in the future if needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using some django modules, then you can detect tables in schema, by looking for used app names and also for main django tables. These are:

```
django_admin_log
django_content_type
django_session
django_site
```

And for auth app from django:

```
auth_group
auth_group_permissions
auth_message
auth_permission
auth_user
auth_user_groups
auth_user_user_permissions
```

Just look for apps that you use from django and tables for those apps will have app name prefix. Those you must drop.